# Is there any way to improve this code?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

```
SELECT 
    tblstud.studid,
    tblsched.ip 
FROM tblstud 
LEFT JOIN tblstudsched 
    ON (tblstud.studid=tblstudsched.studid) 
LEFT JOIN tblsched 
    ON (tblstudsched.schedid=tblsched.schedid) 
WHERE 
    tblstud.rfidid='".$rfid."' 
    AND tblsched.ip='".$ip."' 
    AND EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT tblsched.schedid 
        FROM tblsched 
        INNER JOIN tblstudsched 
        WHERE 
            tblstudsched.schedid=tblsched.schedid 
            AND NOW() BETWEEN tblsched.timein AND tblsched.timeout
    )
```

This is my code so far. It is designed to be done after Arduino microcontroller sends data to PHP. It takes me about 8 seconds before another data is to be accepted. I haven't checked the Arduino side but I think it's fast enough when I did another different MySQL query but that one is relatively shorter than the one above.

The tables are in Inno DB but I'll try MyISAM later since the latter is the best when there are more reads than adding data.

The data types are `varchar` with ranges varying from 3-30 characters each.

I'm confident also with the speed of the laptop I'm using.

Comment: How do you maintain 15-line queries on one line with a half-mile wide horizontal scroll bar? Also note that as soon as you apply filters in the where clause on tables connected by outer join, those joins become inner. At least that's how it should work in proper RDBMS (MySQL is kind of famous for being really lax on silly things like relational rules).

Comment: Hahahaha I don't know why but when I post the code, only the first part is being considered a code, so I decided to remove the "new lines" and voila it's the hard-to-read two-liner code, pardon me. Anyway, thanks for the idea.

Comment: I suggest you add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` for all 3 tables and the execution plan of this query.

Comment: I don't think the EXISTS subquery is necessary. You're already joining those tables in the main query using the same keys. You should be able to replace everything from AND EXISTS... with the single condition beginning with AND NOW(), e.g. "WHERE tblstud.rfidid='".$rfid."' AND tblsched.ip='".$ip."' AND NOW() BETWEEN tblsched.timein AND tblsched.timeout"

Comment: @dartonw Thanks, that's what I'm implementing now.

Comment: The `EXISTS` may be necessary. It depends on what the query is supposed to do. Which we have no idea. @Jeff, perhaps you can explain (what the query is supposed to do).

Comment: The idea is to check whether a student belongs to a certain subject he is enrolled in. and whether the time(dt) he enters a room (ip) is within timein and timeout of the sched he is enrolled in and whether he is into the room that the subj has been assigned to. tblstud includes the rfidid and studid. tblsched includes the schedule, ip (the room assigned) , timein and timeout. tblstudsched includes the subject that is associated with the subj (that he is enrolled) tblattend includes the rfidid, dt(time he entered) and the ip(room he entered).tblattend is the table to be compared to 3 other tbl